# Massive SVN Name refactoring

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have to change ("refactoring" is the proper name) a lot of branch names in my SVN repo (For migration to git, many branch names are equal to some tag names and that broke the migration). With the plugin of eclipse subversion, it is not possible to rename all the branches togther so I have to do it one by one (almost impossible too). I was looking a way to automate this. I must keep all the history of the branches and directories.

I appreciate your help, love this community.

Comment: Do you have a list of branches somewhere that you know to rename? Because if so, you can always write like a simple php or batch script or something that just loops through the list of names and does an `svn mv` on each URL in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to accomplish this with an svn client.  Changing the name of the branch and committing it will still leave the old name in history - and it will collide.

You said you must keep all the history... However, the easiest thing to do is to exclude the branches and keep the tags.

If you need all those old branches, you can dump the repo with `svn dump` and then use sed to rename the branches (or the tags)